# How do I randomly change the color of a circle?

Tags: random, view, swiftui

I'm beginning to try out SwiftUI. I want the Circle is randomly changing the color from red or green.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var colorCircle = [".red", ".green"]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.colorCircle.randomElement())
                .frame(width: 100,
                       height: 100)
                .position(x: 250,
                          y: 320)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make your `colorCircle` array to contain *Colors* and not *Strings*.

```
@State var colorCircle: [Color] = [.red, .green]
```

Also note you're trying to access `colorCircle` from inside the `Color` struct:

```
Color.colorCircle.randomElement()
```

As you declared `colorCircle` in the `ContentView` you can use it like:

```
self.colorCircle.randomElement()
```

or (shorter):

```
colorCircle.randomElement()
```

Then you can use `randomElement`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var colorCircle: [Color] = [.red, .green]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(colorCircle.randomElement()!)
                .frame(width: 100,
                       height: 100)
                .position(x: 250,
                          y: 320)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `randomElement()` returns an optional so you can force-unwrap it (`!`) if you're sure your array is not empty.

However, as a good practice, I recommend not to use `!` and provide default values if possible:

```
.fill(colorCircle.randomElement() ?? .red)
```